# how to write chrome extension logs to file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi I'm working with the chrome extension and I would like to save the console.log items to file so that I could retain the logs and review it. Is there any way to save log in chrome extension.

Found chrome.filesystem but it cant be used in chrome extension. read that chrom.filesystem is using in chrome ap to save the log. also cant use the fs package like we are using in the javascript program.

Comment: Extensions can't do that directly. You can use HTML5 FileSystem, the upcoming Native File System API, or a [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) API, look for further info using these keywords.

Comment: i tried to use html5 file system but it is not supporting in chrome extension

Comment: It should be supported so either you did it incorrectly or there's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: how can we fix the bug in chrome reinstalling chrome can fix the issue??